# Node backend deployed to AWS S3 bucket - what is the end point URL for back end

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a react app stored on an AWS S3 bucket and it seems to be working fine.
I have an RDS database that is up and running and I have the end point for it.
I have a node app that is running express and everything needed to take a request from the front end and "place" the data in the RDS database using that end point.

My question is - When the node app is deployed to the S3 bucket, what URL do I use in the front end to call the node app back end in the S3 bucket?

We have a similar setup at my work and the end point for calling the back end (S3 bucket with Node) from the front end is something like ...

```
https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev    
https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/prod
```

I am not sure if I need to set up an api gateway or something to facilitate the routing of the call?

Comment: S3 cannot run code.  Those URLs are for an API Gateway endpoint, pointing to something like a Lambda, or ECS, or EC2 deployment.  Those backends might use S3, but whatever it is, it's more than just S3.

Comment: That's what I thought, I just can't figure out how to duplicate it and I'm not quite sure how to set up and run a node back end on an ECS or EC2.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, AWS s3 are for just static content. So you can only deploy a static websites on AWS s3 but not the nodejs app, as it will need node as a runtime.

If you want to replicate, then as mentioned its must be behind API gateway. so you need to understand the nderlying deployment resources which  can be lambda, ecs or ec2. API gateway just route your traffic to the deployment.

[AWS API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/apigateway.html)

If you are just trying to run your backend with a few steps then  AWS EC2 or AWS lightsail is the quicker option.

**Ec2:**

With EC2 you will need to configure and install each and everything for example nodejs runtime, npm etc

**lightsail:**

In lightsail you just need to select the node version and that's it.
Here are few docs that can help you to deploy your app using lightsale, lightsale instance come with nodejs version and does not need any installation, you just need to copy your code to the instance and start.

Once you able to deploy the app either on ec2 or lightsale, you just to copy the public IP from lightsale or ec2 and use that IP in the frontend app.

[deploy-nodejs-app-in-aws-lightsail](https://akshaykrisonz.medium.com/deploy-nodejs-app-in-aws-lightsail-9ba75332a89c)

[amazon-lightsail-quick-start-guide-nodejs](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-quick-start-guide-nodejs)

[deploy-node-js-server-on-aws-lightsail](https://fitdevops.in/deploy-node-js-server-on-aws-lightsail/)

Comment: let me update .